# Tag Manager Trigger Event When Text Appears in Div

Tags: google-analytics, form-submit, google-tag-manager

How would I set-up Tag Manager so that it triggers an event only when a div has text in it?

I have an email sign-up landing page, where once a user submits an email address on the page, the server sends back a success or failure response either in the div id=mce-error-response or div id=mce-success-response (see below). How should I implement Tag Manager so that it can track the response?

```
<form action="[]" method="post" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" class="validate" target="_blank" novalidate>
          <div id="mc_embed_signup_scroll">
            <input type="email" value="" name="EMAIL" class="email" id="mce-EMAIL" placeholder="email address" required style="float: left;">

            <div style="position: absolute; left: -5000px; float: left;" aria-hidden="true">
              <input type="text" name="[]" tabindex="-1" value="">
            </div>
            <div class="clear">
              <input type="submit" value="NOTIFY ME" name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="button" style="float: left;">
            </div>
          </div>
          <br>
          <div id="mce-responses" class="clear" style="color: #fff">
            <div class="response" id="mce-error-response"></div>
            <div class="response" id="mce-success-response"></div>
            </div>
        </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a DOM variable in GTM and set your ID as `mce-success-response`and leave the attribute name blank. Use the variable in a form submission trigger and set your condition (i.e - `matches RegEx .*' ). Lastly configure an event tag that that corresponds with the trigger and passes the label in the DOM form field.

For more information read over this blog - an oldie but still relevant: http://www.simoahava.com/analytics/form-tracking-google-tag-manager/

Comment: Thanks! I'll give this try.

Answer (score -1):

You would have to do something like When the form is submitted set a time out for 3 second(Possibly more) and in the timeout function check for div text and if it matches your requirement push and event to GTM / GA.

Hope this helps,

Cheers Analytics ML.

Comment: Thanks! I'll give this try, as well.